# Run a Ruby command prompt in a browser

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems

I've written a game in Ruby. Currently the only way to interact with it is with a CLI. It's packaged up as a gem.

I would like to put it on a website, for people to use. How would I go about that?

To clarify, I want a browser window that has a command prompt (like http://tryruby.org), that loads my gem first. I'm familiar with Heroku which I presume is the avenue of choice for this?

Comment: write a rails or sinatra app with a form and test it locally. come back here when you have specific questions that you cannot figure out?

Comment: This is somewhat difficult because the browser can't run Ruby code. There are some tools [gotty](https://github.com/yudai/gotty) for example which are like SSH for the browser; they will mirror the CLI socket over websocket. However you have to be careful about security if you allow writes; if a user presses control+c, can they wreck havoc on the system?

Comment: burnettk I have no idea how to make a form (or any web construct) that resembles the behaviour of irb, I did google around but found nothing.
@maxpleaner gotty looks interesting. Thanks.However I just found the source code for tryruby.org (https://github.com/Sophrinix/TryRuby) so I'll have a look at that. This is all a bit more complex than I hoped though :/

Comment: @reedstonefood: Well, yes, having arbitrary people execute arbitrary code on your server in a secure manner is obviously complex. `FileUtils.rm_rf('/')`, anyone?

Comment: @reedstonefood did you get a solution for this? I have a similar problem to yours: I want to allow for a simple IRB to be available for people to use from their browser - without any server involved. Is such a thing even possible?